# Publicly available pools for lap/lane swimming near Itaewon in Seoul, SK?

Tags: seoul, swimming

We'll be staying in Seoul for the month of January, in the Itaewon district, and i am wondering if there are swimming pools that are open for lane/lap swimming for visitors for a daily fee (no membership required). Ideally they would have locker rooms, showers, and even better, easy to read signage.

Thank you (고맙습니다)